# adjust the width as the rest width of parent

Tags: css

guys Im having problem with responsive tricks.
Assume we have a parent div which has 500px of the width. And the childs are a 200px div and auto width div. I know the rest width of parent availible is 300px because 200px already taken. Now I want  second div (which is auto width) to cover the rest width - whole the entire width  - .
am doing so bacuse the parent will be resized as the window resizes and the first div is all the time 200px but the second div is unknown from the width.
I know hot to do so with js but It must be totally static.
thanks.

Comment: So do you want the modifications to remain responsive?

Comment: I got the answer. I used calc(100% - 200px) and worked fine